# How do I speed up a for loop with unrelated data?

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop, parallel-processing

A very simple example of passing an array of integers to a for loop shown below. If those integers are unrelated to each other, how can I make it so that a "for loop" iterates over all of them at the same time?

```
int waffles[3] = { 0 };

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    waffles[i] = i;
}
```

What I get

clock 1: waffles[0] = 0;

clock 2: waffles[1] = 1;

clock 3: waffles[2] = 2;

What I want

clock 1: waffles[0] = 0, waffles[1] = 1, waffles[2] = 2

Comment: That is a naive assumption about how the CPU will behave. CPUs and C++ are both way more complicated than "1 expression == 1 clock cycle". In C++ you are just describing a *behavior*, not writing machine instructions. The compiler will very likely unroll that loop to the most efficient form for the targeted platform.

Comment: You're likely not getting first variant and very likely that your program will ever run on a cpu which would work as second one (there are specialized ones and some exotic archetictures). But if you want to learn how  parallelize  a loop, you should learn about components for concurrent processing and maybe OpenMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @François Andrieux comment points out:

> The compiler will very likely unroll that loop to the most efficient form for the targeted platform.

See how this code compiles in Godbolt's Compler Explorer [here](https://godbolt.org/z/T481jc).

Clang puts 0 and 1 using the same instruction:

```
        movabs  rax, 4294967296
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 12], rax
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 20], 2
```

gcc puts 1 and 2 using the same instruction:

```
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp], 0
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+4], rax
```

Larger array would result in vectored instructions that put even more data at once (see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/r7K9zh))

Comment: Really? That's actually pretty cool, I didn't know the compilers were smart enough to make optimizations like that. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

This can actually be done using SIMD instructions like the AVX instructions, although it not trivial to implement. You probably want to 100% make sure you are bottlenecked by a specific loop and really NEED to improve performance there.

This might help https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/07/08/improving-performance-with-simd-intrinsics-in-three-use-cases/

(I know this is not a full answer, but I can't comment yet and it might help anyway)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Gilles! I think this qualifies as an answer. No need to apologize for not making a comment ;-)